# Can I use existing shared memory with boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I have shared memory block created in another module.
This wasn't created via boost (that module is written in C).

Can i somehow envelop that shared memory block with a `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory` ?

I'd really like to reduce handling complexity by wrapping it up neatly with a `managed_shared_memory` object.

Or, if this can't be done, can i at least access it nicely with a `managed_shared_memory::handle_t` handle ? or `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr` ?